# Trapping Edit & Update events from DetailsView button clicks

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, event-handling, onclick, code-behind

On an ASP.Net / VB.Net DetailsView that allows inserts, edits, and deletes we would like to trap the event that occurs when a user clicks on the Edit button and the Update button of the DetailsView.

We are looking to trap these events with and event handler inside a VB.Net code-behind file.

Can you tell me with sample code how to do it?

*** Update ***

I tried this coding but get the following error when clicking on the Edit button:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView' 
to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewRow'.
```

This is the coding from the markup showing the Edit button:

```
<asp:DetailsView 
    ID="DetailsViewDetails" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    Height="50px" 
    Width="268px" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDetails"
    DataKeyNames="ID"
    OnItemCommand="DetailsViewDetails_ItemCommand">

    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">

            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                    CommandName="Update" Text="Update"  />
                &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="ButtonCancelUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>

            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonInsert" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                    CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="ButtonCancelInsert" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="ButtonNew" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="New" Text="New" />
                &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />

                    <AjaxToolKit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="deleteButtonConfirmation" 
                        runat="server" 
                        ConfirmText='<%# "You are about to remove: " & vbcr & 
                            Eval("Forename") & vbcr & Eval("Surname") & "!!!" &
                            vbcrlf & "Are you sure you want to do this?" & vbcrlf &
                            "Clicking the OK button will delete this parent." %>'
                        Enabled="True" 
                        TargetControlID="ButtonDelete">

                    </AjaxToolKit:ConfirmButtonExtender>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the handler in the code-behind file:

```
Protected Sub DetailsViewDetails_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewCommandEventArgs)
    Dim row As DetailsViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.CommandSource, Control).NamingContainer, DetailsViewRow)

    Select Case e.CommandName
        Case "Add"

        Case "Edit"
            ' Do this when going into edit mode so changes to the panent's tuition total balance can be updated.
            '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            dcmOriginalRegistrationFee = GetValueFromTextBoxRegistrationFee()

        Case "Delete"

    End Select
End Sub
```

We get the error on the Dim statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it's `ItemCommand` event with an appropriate `CommandName`:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server"  
    OnItemCommand="DetailsView1_ItemCommand" 
    <Fields>
       <asp:BoundField  DataField="IdField" HeaderText="ID" />
       <asp:BoundField  DataField="NameField" HeaderText="Name" />
       <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Add" Text="Add Something" />
       <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Edit" Text="EditSomething" />
       <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete Something" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

in codebehind:

```
Protected Sub DetailsView1_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewCommandEventArgs)
    Select Case e.CommandName
        Case "Add"

        Case "Edit"

        Case "Delete"

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick replies. :-) I will try both approaches. I wish I could select both of your replies as the accepted answer. :-( Maybe Stackoverflow will allow for that in the future. :-)

Comment: Aww come on he's got load of rep ='[ Just kidding, glad to help =]

Comment: We get an error on the Dim statement in the code-behind file. Can you check my coding and see what we missed?

Comment: @Emad-ud-deen: Sorry, mixed the DetailsView with a ListView(GridView etc).  So use the `DetailsView.Rows` property to get all rows.

Comment: Commenting out the Dim statement got rid of the error. It was able to trap e.CommandSource as Edit. Is it possible to get the value from the DetailsView label we named LabelRegistrationFee in that same case statement? If the answer is yes, can you show what coding to use to extract the value in the label?

Comment: You've got the sender which will be the button. Cast `sender` to a button, then use its parent to get the Label. Something like `Dim LabelRegistrationFee As Label = CType(CType(sender, Control).Parent.FindControl("LabelRegistrationFee"), Label)`

Answer (score 3):

You define a function to handle the event.

The events are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview_events.aspx

You would then write a handler, to trap the updating event (before the update happens):

```
Protected Sub detailsView1_ItemUpdating(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles detailsView1.ItemUpdating
    'Code here
End Sub
```

For editing you trap the ModeChanging event:

```
Protected Sub detailsView1_ModeChanging(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles detailsView1.ModeChanging
    'You then check the new edit mode
    If e.NewMode = DetailsViewMode.Edit Then
        'Code here
    End If
End Sub
```

You can also add the handler in your markup for the DetailsView control:

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server" ID="detailsView1" OnItemUpdating="detailsView1_ItemUpdating" OnModeChanging="detailsView1_ModeChanging">
....
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Which means you no longer need to put `Handles detailsView1.ItemUpdating` or `Handles detailsView1.ModeChanging` on the end of your functions.